# How can I create an HTML table with a fixed header that works in mobile phones like IE for windows mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, windows-mobile

How do I create an HTML table with fixed header that works in mobile phones like IE for Windows Mobile?

I have found [this demo](http://cross-browser.com/x/examples/xthf.html).

It is great, however, it does not work in IE in Windows Mobile.

Comment: Why does IE always have to cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript on portable devices is very often seriously lacking.  IE on Windows Mobile has an incomplete Javascript implementation so if it doesn't work that is probably why.

This link may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/iemobile/archive/2007/05/15/ie-mobile-standards-support.aspx